# XPATH: How to select an element that contains some piece of text and its sibling do not contain some other piece of text

Tags: xpath

```
<a>
   <b>
      "Something"
   </b>
   <c>
      "Something else"
   </c>
</a>
<d>
    <e>
     "Something"
    </e>
    <f>
      "Foo"
    </f>
</d>
```

I want to select the elements that contain the text "Something" but don't have siblings containing "Something Else". (In this example I'd want to select 'e')

This is what I've tried

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Something') and ../*[not(contains(text(), 'Something Else'))]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the xpath that you can use.

```
//label[contains(.,'Something') and following-sibling::label[not(contains(.,'Something else'))]]
```

Below is the sample html and the solution screenshot.

```html
<html><head></head><body>
  <div>
   <label>
      "Something"
   </label>
   <label>
      "Something else"
   </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
     "Something"
    </label>
    <label>
      "Foo"
    </label>
</div>
 
</body></html>
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]